How do I remove the "IMAGE MAY NOT BE TO SCALE" mark in the right corner of the button when printing with the Merge eFilm software?
How do I remove the IMAGE MAY NOT BE TO SCALE mark in the right corner of the button when printing with the Merge eFilm software?
Even though I selected User Scaled mode and Scale Factor:100%, it still has the mark.
The IMAGE MAY NOT BE TO SCALE mark is generated by eFilm software.

eFilm software version: 3.4 / 4.0 / 4.1


Update 2024-06-13：

All three modes Fit to size, User Scaled, WYSIWYG cause the mark string on this patient.A DICOM images.
I also checked the DICOM tags data of patient.A, there is no marker string in it.
There is no mark string of patient.A DICOM images in eFilm software reading window.
I change to another patient.B's series of DICOM images, all three modes Fit to size, User Scaled, WYSIWYG don't add the marker string.

I really don't know the reason.



I tried various parameter combinations, but it was no use. My expectation is for the mark not to appear on printed Dicom films.

How do I get the IMAGE MAY NOT BE TO SCALE marking text on a printed film to not display in eFilm?
A: According to the table below, only CT and MR films can not be displayed, which can be done by the method below.
Other types of images will be forced to be displayed by the eFilm software, even if the line of code is deleted using the following method, the eFilm software will force the same marking text to be displayed by itself.
Click on the menu Edit - Properties - Modality Settings - Overlay - Modality Area - and delete the following line:
<ROW><OVERLAYITEM item="M_NotToScale"/></ROW>


Image Type | Marker Removal Instructions
CR IMAGE MAY NOT BE TO SCALE cannot be removed.
CT can be removed
DX IMAGE MAY NOT BE TO SCALE cannot be removed.
ES IMAGE MAY NOT BE TO SCALE can not be removed.
MG IMAGE MAY NOT BE TO SCALE can be removed.
MR can be removed
NM IMAGE MAY NOT BE TO SCALE cannot be removed.
OT IMAGE MAY NOT BE TO SCALE can be removed.
PT IMAGE MAY NOT BE TO SCALE can be removed.
RF IMAGE MAY NOT BE TO SCALE not dropped
RT IMAGE MAY NOT BE TO SCALE
US IMAGE MAY NOT BE TO SCALE
XA IMAGE MAY NOT BE TO SCALE

Another option is to change the eFilm software to another DICOM printing software.


Print to PDF, rather than printer, using WYSIWYG or Fit to Size, whichever remove that caption. An example is shown below, using eFilm Worsktation to open DICOM images, but the DICOM dialog should offer similar options.


Export the image as a file, and edit that file using software such as free IrfanView or other image editor. Again, an example is shown below, using eFilm Worsktation to open DICOM images, but the DICOM dialog should offer similar options.



That said, there are good reasons for the warning when printing a medical X-ray. A surgeon certainly should be alerted if the image does not match the scale of the underlying structure.

Thanks for your help: 1. see my updates, PDF still has markers for this series of DICOM images. 2. Can't modify the printed image because it's printed directly to a blue film printer..

@Infinitecode, Again, change the output printer to use "Print to PDF". or "Export". Illustrations have been added

Print to PDF and Export image to file both contain string marker, I need to remove marker when first printing, not save to file and edit again.
